# Hi, I have problem with the property (title) and the bracket of (bluilder)... I'm just fetch data from API

Tags: flutter

```
class _Requests_TabState extends State<Requests_Tab> {
  Future<Product> productdata = getPostById();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: productdata,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text(snapshot.data.title);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Please elaborate more and clear

Comment: Looks like you're missing a return. Change `CircularProgressIndicator();` to `return CircularProgressIndicator();`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Text(snapshot.data[title].toString());
```